# Login with user using mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, robo3t

Creating a site where users need to login. Can't figure out why it wont let me login, have tried the password with and without md5 cryptation.

Using node.js, express, mongoDB, robomongo.

just the index.js code, link to github.
https://gist.github.com/TimNyl/746df664684595070b27bdc101bff5e9

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Busboy = require('busboy');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var grid = require('gridfs-stream');

var crypto = require('crypto');

var db = new mongo.Db('test', new mongo.Server('127.0.0.1', 27017));
var gfs;

db.open(function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    gfs = grid(db, mongo);
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers : req.headers });
    var fileId = new mongo.ObjectId();
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        console.log('got file', filename, mimetype, encoding);
        var writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({
            _id: fileId,
            filename: filename,
            mode: 'w',
            content_type: mimetype,
        });
        file.pipe(writeStream);
    }).on('finish', function() {
// show a link to the uploaded file
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
        res.end('<a href="/showfile/' + fileId.toString() + '">download     file</a>');
    });
    req.pipe(busboy);
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('login', { title: 'Express' });
});


router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(req.body.password).digest("hex");

    db.collection('user').findOne({ brukernavn: req.body.username, passord: hash }, function(err, doc) {
        if (doc){
            sess = req.session;
            sess.loggedIn = true;
            res.render('index');
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });

});



router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    if(!req.session.loggedIn){
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
    else{
        res.render('index'); // Her gjør vi jobben
    }
});


router.get('/file/:id', function(req, res, next){
    gfs.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, function (err, file) {
        if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
        if (!file) return res.status(404).send('');
        res.set('Content-Type', file.contentType);
        res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' + file.filename + '"');
        var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
            _id: file._id
        });
        readstream.on("error", function(err) {
            console.log("Got error while processing stream " + err.message);
            res.end();
        });
        readstream.pipe(res);
    });
});

router.get('/showfile/:id', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('show', {id: req.params.id});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer to your question, however I did want to mention that you shouldn't use md5hash for passwords - it's too fast (more on this [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure).